# dpkg-dep error: paste subprocess was killed by signal(Broken Pipe) Ubuntu WSL2

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, apt, wsl-2

Hello I am using ubunutu on wsl2 on a windows 10(21h2) machine.
I was updating my apt packages.
then when I put the upgrade command the error in the title. happened.

```bash
~$ sudo apt upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 python3.10 : Depends: libpython3.10-stdlib (= 3.10.4-1+focal2) but 3.10.2-1+focal1 is installed
 python3.10-minimal : Depends: libpython3.10-minimal (= 3.10.4-1+focal2) but 3.10.2-1+focal1 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

when I tried to fix the broken install I get this

```bash
~$ sudo apt --fix-broken install
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  libfwupdplugin1
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove it.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libpython3.10-minimal libpython3.10-stdlib
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libpython3.10-minimal libpython3.10-stdlib
2 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 92 not upgraded.
119 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/2566 kB of archives.
After this operation, 62.5 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 125300 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libpython3.10-stdlib_3.10.4-1+focal2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libpython3.10-stdlib:amd64 (3.10.4-1+focal2) over (3.10.2-1+focal1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libpython3.10-stdlib_3.10.4-1+focal2_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/python3.10/_sysconfigdata__linux_x86_64-linux-gnu.py', which is also in package libpythonThe following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  libfwupdplugin1
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove it.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libpython3.10-minimal libpython3.10-stdlib
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libpython3.10-minimal libpython3.10-stdlib
2 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 92 not upgraded.
119 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/2566 kB of archives.
After this operation, 62.5 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 125300 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libpython3.10-stdlib_3.10.4-1+focal2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libpython3.10-stdlib:amd64 (3.10.4-1+focal2) over (3.10.2-1+focal1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libpython3.10-stdlib_3.10.4-1+focal2_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/python3.10/_sysconfigdata__linux_x86_64-linux-gnu.py', which is also in package libpython3.10-minimal:amd64 3.10.2-1+focal1
Preparing to unpack .../libpython3.10-minimal_3.10.4-1+focal2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libpython3.10-minimal:amd64 (3.10.4-1+focal2) over (3.10.2-1+focal1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libpython3.10-minimal_3.10.4-1+focal2_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/python3.10/typing.py', which is also in package libpython3.10-stdlib:amd64 3.10.2-1+focal1
dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libpython3.10-stdlib_3.10.4-1+focal2_amd64.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libpython3.10-minimal_3.10.4-1+focal2_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

It seems I have fixed the problem.

```bash
sudo dpkg -i --force-overwrite [the path to the libpython3.10 archive folder]
```

and then

```bash
sudo apt -f install
```

Comment: this works, but why? :) can you please explain what is the problem?

Comment: well, from what I can remember. the `-i` over here installs and overwrites the `libpython3.10` then `apt -f install` fixes the broken packages

Comment: yeah thats for sure, but my question is why apt upgrade can't do the overwrite itself and it needs to --force-overwrite.

Comment: That I don't know. let me quickly go ahead and find out.

Answer (score 11):

I keep getting this error trying to install nodejs on my ubuntu 22.04. I've tried @dylandhall solution but it doesn't work

Trying to overwrite `/usr/include/node/node_buffer.h`, which is also in package `libnode-dev 12.22.9~dfsg-1ubuntu3`

> dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe) Errors were encountered while processing: /var/cache/apt/archives/nodejs_16.15.0-deb-1nodesource1_amd64.deb E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

I did this:

```
 sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq libnode-dev
 sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq libnode72:amd64
```

And then `sudo apt-get install -y nodejs` has worked for me.

This is the only solution that worked for me on Ubuntu 22.04. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

@mohammad hosein bahmani

Solution in the answer of @Sasen Perera is from this older post here:

- https://askubuntu.com/questions/1301914/dpkg-deb-error-paste-subprocess-was-killed-by-signal-broken-pipe-nodejs

or here:

- https://askubuntu.com/questions/1062171/dpkg-deb-error-paste-subprocess-was-killed-by-signal-broken-pipe/1062184#1062184

> This process can also occur during upgrading ('sudo apt upgrade'). dpkg has in this case errors processing /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-some/file.deb, which does not exists after the upgrade in the /tmp directory. This .deb file does however exist in the /var/cache/apt/archives and the solution of Olimjon can be applied for this .deb file.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. @ljaniec (sorry for the very late reply)