# dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe) Errors were encountered while processing:

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apt, cudf

I am participating kaggle OTTO Recommendation System competition.
I am trying many other code. I see high ranker use cudf library.
so I want to try it, but I face many errors...
I will show you from the beginning. please help me...

```
E: Unmet dependencies. Try ‘apt —-fix-broken install’ with no packages (or specify & solution)
```

when I tried to fix the broken install I get this

```
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cuda-repo-ubuntu1804-11-4-local/./nvidia-compute-utils-470_470.57.02-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb (--unpack):  
unable to make backup link of './usr/bin/nvidia-cuda-mps-control' before installing new version: Invalid cross-device link
dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe) 
Preparing to unpack .../nvidia-utils-470_470.57.02-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb ... 
Unpacking nvidia-utils-470 (470.57.02-0ubuntu1) ... 
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cuda-repo-ubuntu1804-11-4-local/./nvidia-utils-470_470.57.02-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb (--unpack): 
unable to make backup link of './usr/bin/nvidia-debugdump' before installing new version: Invalid cross-device link 
dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe) 
Errors were encountered while processing: 
/var/cuda-repo-ubuntu1804-11-4-local/./nvidia-compute-utils-470_470.57.02-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb 
/var/cuda-repo-ubuntu1804-11-4-local/./nvidia-utils-470_470.57.02-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb 
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I search this error and I find something solution.

[dpkg-dep error: paste subprocess was killed by signal(Broken Pipe) Ubuntu WSL2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72442108/dpkg-dep-error-paste-subprocess-was-killed-by-signalbroken-pipe-ubuntu-wsl2)

```
sudo dpkg -i --force-overwrite /var/cuda-repo-ubuntu1804-11-4-local/./nvidia-compute-utils-470_470.57.02-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
```

when I tried to this I get error... this..

```
(Reading database ... 31 files and directories currently installed.) 
Preparing to unpack .../nvidia-compute-utils-470_470.57.02-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb ... 
Unpacking nvidia-compute-utils-470 (470.57.02-0ubuntu1) ... 
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cuda-repo-ubuntu1804-11-4-local/./nvidia-compute-utils-470_470.57.02-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb (--install): 
unable to make backup link of './usr/bin/nvidia-cuda-mps-control' before installing new version: Invalid cross-device link 
dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe) 
Errors were encountered while processing: 
/var/cuda-repo-ubuntu1804-11-4-local/./nvidia-compute-utils-470_470.57.02-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
```

What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, does your machine have a compatible GPU?  Are you using WSL2?  If it does and you are, please follow the installation instructions on on https://rapids.ai/wsl2.  You should not need to install NVIDIA drivers or CUDA on your WSL2 instance.  You may need to redo your instance, so please follow the instructions Microsoft [may] provides (found in one of the links in the Install section) Good luck, with your Kaggle competition!